# Unable to use WIFI after installing Windows Server 2008 R2 - drivers cannot be found

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, drivers, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a Toshiba Satellite A500 (laptop) and after installing Windows server 2008 R2 to it I can't connect to any wifi. The problem is that the drivers are not installed correctly. I can connect to the internet with ethernet. I went to device manager (in control panel) and the wifi network adapter is in the "Other devices" tab, when I try to install the drivers it says that it couldn't find any.
The network card is a Realtek RTL8191SE-VB. I've already tried to download the drivers from the official website but I can't install them because it says that they don't give support to this operating system.
I've already enabled the wifi connections to the OS, but the problem still remains (because it's with the drivers).
Hope someone had the same problem and could fix it :D and sorry for my bad english.
Thanks!

edit: the network card just disappeared from device manager

Comment: Please post VEN and DEV of your network card. (*Device Manager* -> *Properties* -> *Details* tab -> Select *Hardware Ids* from the list)

Comment: What do you mean by "enabled wifi connections in the OS"? Have you read this http://www.win2008r2workstation.com/wireless-networking/

Comment: the hardware just disappeared from Device Manager

Comment: yeah, Jonny, that's what I mean by "enabled wifi connection in the OS"